# Best development framework for both desktop and mobile apps which can also be connected to raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, desktop-application, mobile-application

I want to develop an app which can be used in mobile phones and desktops and laptops. The app should be compatible to all mobile phone Operating Systems(Android, iOS etc.). The app should also be connected to Raspberry Pi. So please suggest me the best **free framework** for this purpose.

Comment: Questions asking for a software recommendations are off-topic here. This should be asked at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I couldn't find the right tags there and so I posted my question here.

Comment: Arduino should work.

Comment: I want it to be connected to raspberry pi.